understanding the dimension theorem proof and analysing it
background : finished linear algebra 1 learning linear algebra 2, I am trying to reach a solid understanding of the theorems we learnt and  prove them on my own ,while connecting them to previous concepts, I will provide my reasoning for the proof wrote and thought process , if some feedback, logic errors , can be given and maybe a different approach with a different thought process either will be a vital learning experience
what I understand is the following
a linear transformation applied on a vector , can be thought of as a matrix multiplication ,I know that the rank of the matrix can stay the same or get lower, for the sake of the proof I will be switching between thinking of T as  matrix multiplication with the vector $ \vec{v} \in  F^n$  and thinking of it as a linear combination of the matrix columns where the vector gets mapped to in lets say $F^m $ $\vec{b} \in F^m $
$ T_{A}\vec{v}=\vec{b} $ $\implies A  $ $ m x  n  $
realising  that T can be a linear transformation that is not a change of basis matrix where all the columns are linearly independent  , I  considered that the vector in the matrix I have can be linearly dependent and they should map to zero because  I am thinking of T as function applied to the basis if it is applied to the basis then the basis should lead to different vectors if they are not leading to different vectors then they are not linearly independent one is a combination of the other leading to the same place but in the end I can reach any dependent vector from the independent ones , so they will not  add any new information
so $T_{A}\vec{v}=\vec{b}$
so from V=$F^n$ to W=$F^m$
where dimV is n and dim of W  is m  if b is the basis of V then c is a linear combination of the basis , where the matrix multiplication is a combination of the columns so we are getting the column vector space which is a subset of V and it can have a   basis k less or equal to n  , and if I look at the null space instead the vectors that go to zero lowering the dimension I get that the basis for the solution are of rank n-k    meaning that the dim(Ker(T)) +dim(image (T))  = V
with this we retrieve the  info of the rank of the dimension we got our vector from, now I will write it formally without the thought process
Let's denote $\dim(\ker(T)) = k$. We choose a basis for $\ker(T)$:
$ \ker(T) = \operatorname{sp}(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k) $
We extend this basis to a basis for $V$ since ker(T) is subspace of V  and has basis less or equal to V:
$ V = \operatorname{sp}(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k, b_{k+1}, \ldots, b_n) $
Define:
$ B = \{ b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n \} $
We consider the image under $T$:
$ \operatorname{Im}(T) = T(V) = T(\operatorname{sp}(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k, b_{k+1}, \ldots, b_n)) $
Since $T(b_i) = 0$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$ (because they are in the kernel of $T$), we have:
$ \operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{sp}(T(b_{k+1}), T(b_{k+2}), \ldots, T(b_n)) $
Thus, the vectors $T(b_{k+1}), T(b_{k+2}), \ldots, T(b_n)$ form a basis for $\operatorname{Im}(T)$.
Therefore:
$ \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) = n - k $
So:
$ \dim(\ker(T)) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) = k + (n - k) = n = \dim(V) $
Hence proved:
$ \dim(\ker(T)) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) = \dim(V) $

What is your question?

it is written at the top just proof checking logic understanding and any different approach to prove the dimension theorem , all works  I am just trying to reach an understanding of the basics of the topics at hand

Your proof is almost correct! The only thing is you need to argue why it is that $Tb_{k+1},\dots,Tb_n$ form a basis for $\text{im } T$. First we will argue that they are linearly independent. Suppose $\sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i T b_i=0$ for $a_i \in F$, where $F$ is the field underlying our vector space. Then by linearity of $T$ we have that $T(\sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i b_i)=0$. However, we know that since $B$ is linearly independent, this holds true only when $\sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i b_i=0$ (since no linear combination of $b_i$ for $k+1\leq i \leq n$ will give us a linear combination of $b_j$ for $1\leq j \leq k$). But the $\{b_i\}_{i=k+1}^n$ are linearly independent, thus $a_i=0$ for all $k+1\leq i\leq n$. This shows that $\sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i T b_i=0$ implies $a_i=0$ for all $i$, that is, $\{T b_i\}_{i=k+1}^n$ is linearly independent. By definition of the image, we know that every member of $\text{im }T$ may be written as some linear combination of the (nonzer) $T b_i$, thus $\{T b_i\}_{i=k+1}^n$ spans $\text{im }T$. This completes your proof.
There are other ways to prove it, provided you know a bit of abstract algebra (specifically module theory). In particular, suppose $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation between two vector spaces $V,W$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $V/\ker T\simeq \text{im }T$. Thus $\dim(V/\ker T)=\dim(\text{im }T)$. But we have that $\dim(V/\ker T)=\dim(V)-\dim(\ker T)$, from which our desired result follows. Now, we still need to show that $\dim(V/U)=\dim(V)-\dim(U)$, which I believe is somewhat similar to the proof I show in the previous paragraph, however, it has the advantage that it is slightly more general as well as being far more intuitive (once you understand quotients of vector spaces).
Hope this helps!

could not ask for more ! this is really useful  much appreciated

Glad it helped! Feel free to accept this answer since it was what you're looking for! :)

totally ,thanks for the patience
